# setBounds проблема со скрытым блоком

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В общем, суть проблемы в том, что карта инициализируется, потом в какой-то момент N  вызывается setBounds. Видимо, из-за того, что блок в котором находится карта выставлен в display:none, метод отрабатывает некорректно с точки зрения задуманной мной логики. Даже если метод вызвать непосредственно после перехода блока из display:none в display:block он отрабатывает некорректно. Ему нужен какой-то таймаут. Иначе говоря, нужно каким-то образом понять, когда карта готова к setBounds.

Comment: Приведите пример кода на jsfiddle.net, где можно увидеть испытываемые трудности.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jd5ek1mg/ К примеру. Выставляем блок с картой в display:none - setBounds отработает только в том случае, если сделать его по окончании анимации fadeIn, что довольно неудобно, поскольку в таком случае придется сообщать карте эту информацию извне. По мимо прочего, даже если сообщать карте момент окончания анимации всё равно setBounds, порой, отрабатывает некорректно, вынося объекты за обозримые пределы. Два под ряд setBounds позволяет избежать этой ситуации, но она тоже довольно абсурдна.

Answer (score 0):

В песочнице Яндекс есть целых два примера отрисовки карты "из пустоты".

1. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/hiddendiv
2. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/request_map/

А если уж карта вызывается вручную, то вообще нет никакой необходимости запускать её автоматом после прогрузки DOM-структуры страницы.
Просто пропишите запуск **init()** при нажатии кнопки.

```
$(".clicker").on("click", function () {
    $("#map").fadeIn();
    init()
});
//ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6w01zbyd/